# Enterprise Library Logging Exceptions to the database (with custom information)

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

The Enterprise Library comes with logging to the database however how do you configure to store exception information/fields in multiple columns?
In addition how would you extend to store contextual information like user, web ui, stored procedure parameters and names etc. in different database columns.

I would like to have exceptions from business, data and UI layers stored in the database in different columns (not just one big field)

thanks